# Support for crypto-currencies like Bitcoin

Tags: civicontribute, payment-processor, payment

Our organization would like to start taking donations in the form of bitcoin.  Is there any functionality out there I can use to integrate this within a CiviCRM-generated contribution page?  Thanks for any help.

Using 4.7.29 on Wordpress 4.9.2

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [BitPay](https://civicrm.org/blog/andyw/bitcoin-payment-processing-with-bitpay) payment processor.

Comment: I did see that page, but it's from 2014, and in Github it was last updated on Oct 1, 2014.  Is anyone actually using or supporting this?

Comment: @ruthD I know someone who is - or was until recently, the regulatory landscape changed in their area - but I'm not comfortable sharing my client name in public.  Find me at https://chat.civicrm.org (username is "junglebird") and I'll make a connection to my client, who is also available in chat.  Also - their use predated me, and I only learned about it when they stopped using it, which is why I don't feel qualified to answer your question directly, sorry!

Comment: I found out that the developer of this extension, Andy Walker, is no longer working at Circle Interactive, and CI says they had/have no direct involvement in this extension.  So I think the code for it has been abandoned.  Jon's client says it always worked well for them, but since my org doesn't have any developers (nor funds to hire them) I think we need to find another solution.

Comment: I'm likely to be starting work on reviving the bitpay extension for CiviCRM 5.x in early October as I have a client who is willing to fund this.  Contact me on chat.civicrm.org - mattwire

Comment: I got the bitpay processor working and did make some updates that I fed back to the developer. I haven't used it in awhile though. I posted notes on how to get it working at https://njlp.org/22-administration/website/1623-how-to-accept-bitcoin-using-civicrm